# Why am I getting parsing error when opening APK file from app cache?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to download an APK file online from within my app and then install it using Java. My code basically, downloads the file to the device from my server and then uses an Intent to open the installation message from the package manager and allow the app to be installed.

It works perfectly for me... unless I save the file to cache instead of regular storage. If I save it to cache instead, I get an error that it could not parse the APK file.

I checked and it is downloading the entire file to the cache correctly, but it just not installing. Any ideas?

The only difference in my code is that instead of using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/file.apk"` I'm trying to use `context.getCacheDir() + "/file.apk"` as for my file path.

I want to put the file in the cache so that Android can handle the cleaning of the file and so that I don't need to worry about handling write permissions on different Android versions and the variations of dealing with external storage.

Comment: Cache might be limited and thus corrupting the file possibly, how big is the APK?

Comment: I'm testing with a 3MB APK, but at release it will be an 80MB-90MB APK.

Comment: Hmm one thing to check is try it on an emulator and confirm that the file was written properly by checking the Md5 of what you wrote and comparing to the expected. If its not the same, then something happened with your write. i looked up limitations in cache and there doesn't seem to be limitations.. minus the fact that if the device gets low on storage it will remove the file.

Comment: The APK getting removed, is primarily why I want to write to cache instead of storage, so that Android will clean the file automatically on its own. The file appears to be writing correctly. Thought maybe it was a permissions issue, but I checked on Android 5 (which doesn't require the elevated permissions that Android 7+ needs), but still no use. I'm beginning to wonder if maybe it's an Android security limitation.

Comment: Looking at this, it says your cache shouldn't exceed 1MB https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#InternalCache ... not sure how true that is

Comment: Since the Facebook app uses over 100MB of my cache, I'm going to guess it's not a hard-cap :)